# Json.NET Prevent JsonProperty from deserializing (in order to deserialize it manually afterwards)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Json.NET in a Web API and I have a request class that looks like this:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public JRaw Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to receive values of different types in the `Value` property (e.g. `string`, `bool`, `array[]`, `object`, etc.).

I want to manually deserialize the `Value` property, because I have some custom converters that I want to use for the particular case.

For example, I have a `StringDateTimeConverter` (which can convert `ISO_8601` strings and `UNIX timestamps`).

Here is how I deserialize the `Value` property:

```
object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(model.Value.ToString(), systemType, serailizerSettings);
```

where `systemType` is `System.DateTime` in this particular case and I've added my `StringDateTimeConverter` to the `serializerSettings` converters.

The problem is that each time my converter receives a `System.DateTime` object instead of a `string`, which means that it still deserializes the `Value` property.

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent the property from deserializing?

Obviously, I've tried using `JRaw`, which I guess is primarily used in serialization (not deserialization), and `object` as types for the `Value` property.

**Note** Using a custom converter for the `Model` class is not an option for me since I need to deserialize the `Value` property after some server-side logic that chooses the right type of converter to use for the deserialization of the `Value` property.

Comment: [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm)?

Comment: [JsonIgnore] would seem the way forwards. Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731320/serialize-property-but-do-not-deserialize-property-in-json-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTimeStringConverter gets an already DateTime converted object in ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53508910/10263)

Comment: Dates and times are recognized by `JsonTextReader` not the serializer.  To disable this completely set `DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None` as shown in [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694/3744182) or [json.net: DateTimeStringConverter gets an already DateTime converted object in ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509380/3744182).

Comment: To disable this at the class level, apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(DateParseHandlingConverter), DateParseHandling.None)]` to `Model` as shown in [How to prevent a single object property from being converted to a DateTime when it is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644970/3744182).

Comment: Do either of those options answer your question?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for. If I mark the property with JsonIgnore it won't receive any value at all (it'll always be null).

Comment: @dbc Thank you for your answer, it did solve my problem. I ended up doing a custom converter where I set the DateParseHandling to None, just like in the example you sent. Do you want to post your comment as an answer, so that I can mark it.

Comment: If you used the same converter we could just mark this as a duplicate.  You could upvote that answer if it helped.