# Handling invalid date string format from consumed open api in c# with a custom jsonConverter

Tags: json, json.net, swagger, openapi, date-formatting

I need to consume an api based on a swagger definition on swaggerhub that specifies a fields as LastPriceChange string($date) which becomes a DateTime in the  generated model in c#.

The problem is they provide the data in an invalid format  :

"LastPriceChange": "2020-11-23 16:15:57Z",

because the T to specify the time part is missing the following error is thrown when reserializing the string :

String '2020-11-23 16:15:57Z' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I already have a custom json converter I had to write for an integer field they return null for, but this seems harder to write. Is there a good way to identify through the data contract or some other way, that the field should be a date in ajson converter?

If not is there another way to map this field to a DateTime?

In the serializer settings I have tried playing with the following values :

```
 DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        DateFormatString = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ",
```

Is there any other way to get round this problem?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Json.Net has special code in the reader to try to automatically parse strings that look like ISO 8601 dates. But this will interfere with a custom date converter. If you're trying to do date parsing in a converter, you should set `DateParseHandling` to `None` so that you will receive the actual string in your `ReadJson` method. Then you can parse it any way you like. See [DateTimeStringConverter gets an already DateTime converted object in ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53508910/10263).

Comment: By the way, I think you have your date format specified incorrectly.  It should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"` with lowercase `y` for the year and lowercase `d` for the day.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer. correcting the date format gets past the problem without need for a custom converter (although it strips the time, but that ok in this case). thanks

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brian's helpful comments this was because I set the date fromat string wrong to try and work around it:

```
DateFormatString = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ",
```

this should actually have been

```
DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
```