# How to read raw json value when using NewtonsoftJson in controller

Tags: c#, json.net

I have several models with DateTime properties. These models are DTOs for accepting in my controller methods.
What I am trying to do is to remove timezone if a client sends it.
Example:

```
class InputDto {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public DateTime? dt {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a method that accepts it

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DoWork([FromBody] InputDto content)
{
   ...
}
```

If a client sent body with value "dt":"2023-01-01T00:00:00.000+07:00" I would like to have property dt equals "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000".

What I did:

1. Created a class DateTimeConverter  which inherits from DateTimeConverterBase
2. Overridden the CanConvertMethod

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)  
{  
  return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);  
}
```

3. Overridden the ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) method
4. Registered my converter

```
services.AddControllers()
   .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
      options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter()))
```

When I debug the ReadJson method I am getting the value from JsonReader argument but the value inside it is already been converted to my timezone.

If there any way to work with raw data in this method? Or is there any other way to do it?

P.S.: I know that I should have changed my property type to DateTimeOffset, but actually I don't want to do this.

Comment: There is no way to get the raw JSON value once `JsonTextReader` has parsed it to a `DateTime`. You need to set [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_dateparsehandling.htm) at some higher level.  See [json.net: DateTimeStringConverter gets an already DateTime converted object in ReadJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53508910/3744182) and [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694).

Comment: If you can't modify your JsonSerializerSettings you can disable DateParseHandling by applying a converter to the container object, here `InputDto`.  See [How to prevent a single object property from being converted to a DateTime when it is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644970/3744182).  Does that answer your question?